# Adding a pattern (hashed, dots...) to dots on QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology

I want to use dots to mark some locations but different shades of grey are not enough to differentiate them. I would prefer filling the dots with some pattern, like hash or dots. Is there a way to do this?

The pictures show the dots that I am using and the patterns that I would like to have in the dots.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can style the points using a `Filled Marker` made of a `Point Pattern Fill` that itself contains the `Simple Marker` of your choice.

The inner `simple markers` should be very small and possibly the fill and stroke colors should be the same.

[image]